# Snowflake query slowness

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowsql

Did anyone observed slowness when querying data from snowflake(select statement)  with OS Windows 2016 + pycharm environment.
Getting result  quickly  with window 10 OS with same environment.

When checked network performance using wireshark, round trip time is more with windows 10 when compared with window 2016.

Other difference is window  10 is on physical on-prem system and windows 2016 is workspace in AWS.

Any one experienced slowness with similar setup as above.

Any suggestion to troubleshoot further.

Comment: check snowflake history for more details and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

Do you think the query execution at Snowflake is slow?
Have you compared the query execution time by keeping other conditions (like warehouse size, load on the warehouse) the same?

If the slowness is in data transfer over network, it could be because of AWS region etc, not to mention several other factors that could impact network data transfer speeds.
Snowflake's query execution performance should not be impacted based on your location or OS etc.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake is running as a SaaS on the cloud. In Ragesh's case I think it is running on AWS. So, from a query performance perspective on snowflake, it ideally should not matter whether you are initiating the connection from a Windows 2010 or 2016. But the network bandwidth may be a factor to consider. Your bandwidth on premise may not be as good as when you are on AWS. To be sure about that. Can you please do this test.

Run your query with Windows 10 - Before running the query, please set a query tag like

ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_TAG ='ONPREMISE';

Run your query with Windows 16 - Before running the query, please set a query tag like

ALTER SESSION SET QUERY_TAG ='ONAWS';

After this, go to Snwoflake console history view and filter based on query_tag and share the query profile details for both the scenarions